# How to fix "Blob object must have non-null data for this operation. (line 6, file "Code")" in google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to create a duplicate file and then send it via email, but I'm getting error:

> Blob object must have non-null data for this operation. (line 6, file "Code")

I've tried to change:

```
var duplicatedFileId = sourceFile.makeCopy(sourceFile+" copy", sourceFolder).getId();
```

Into:

```
var duplicatedFileId = sourceFile.makeCopy(sourceFile+" copy", sourceFolder).getId().toString();
```

But I got another error.

```
function myFunction() {
  var sourceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1DiqneJbyPN90SvE7uGaesdrd7Po6NJLl");
  var sourceFile = DriveApp.getFileById("1qAabbU8MlWmV8J1rdI5A8eEvUPLXAqKnz6fp1vxUOzQ");
  var duplicatedFileId = sourceFile.makeCopy(sourceFile+" copy", sourceFolder).getId();
  var duplicatedFile = DriveApp.getFileById(duplicatedFileId);
  GmailApp.sendEmail("someone@gmail.com", "Testing attaching a file", "This is a test email", {
    attachments:[duplicatedFile.getAs(MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS)],
    name:sourceFile+" copy"
  });
}
```

I expected the duplicate file to be sent, but I got error:

> Blob object must have non-null data for this operation. (line 6, file "Code").

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function runTwo() {
  var sourceFolder=DriveApp.getFolderById("1DiqneJbyPN90SvE7uGaesdrd7Po6NJLl");
  var sourceFile=DriveApp.getFileById("1qAabbU8MlWmV8J1rdI5A8eEvUPLXAqKnz6fp1vxUOzQ");
  var duplicatedFileId = sourceFile.makeCopy(sourceFile.getName() + "_copy", sourceFolder).getId();
  var duplicatedFile = DriveApp.getFileById(duplicatedFileId);
  GmailApp.sendEmail("someone@gmail.com", "Testing attaching a file", "This is a test email", {attachments:[duplicatedFile]});
}
```

Changed this line `var duplicatedFileId = sourceFile.makeCopy(sourceFile+" copy", sourceFolder).getId();` to this line `var duplicatedFileId = sourceFile.makeCopy(sourceFile.getName() + "_copy", sourceFolder).getId();`

and this line `GmailApp.sendEmail("someone@gmail.com", "Testing attaching a file", "This is a test email", {
    attachments:[duplicatedFile.getAs(MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS)],
    name:sourceFile+" copy"
  });` to this line `GmailApp.sendEmail("someone@gmail.com", "Testing attaching a file", "This is a test email", {attachments:[duplicatedFile]});`